# Random number generator which order the numbers from small to big

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to write a function which generates a number from 0 to 90, and return that number to the HTML file. I'm trying to order it from small to big, this is my code but it's not ordering it.

```
var timeStart = 0;

function timeGenerator(timeStart) {
    var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 1);
    if (time > timeStart) {
        timeStart = time;
    } 
    return timeStart; 
}  
document.getElementById("Scorers").innerHTML += '<p>'+Scorers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)]+' '+timeGenerator(timeStart)+"'</p>";
```

Comment: Please describe your problem clearly. What you are trying to expect, and what are the unexpected results?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I edit my answer, I hope this code would help you:

```
var Players = ["Player1", "Player2", "Player3"];
var Scorers = [];

function newScore(player, time){
    tuple = [time, player];
    Scorers.push(tuple);
}

newScore(Players[0], parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*90+1)), 10);
newScore(Players[1], parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*90+1)), 10);
newScore(Players[2], parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*90+1)), 10);

// Order
Scorers.sort(function(current, next){ return current[0] - next[0];});

for (i=0; i < Scorers.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("Scorers").innerHTML += '<p>'+Scorers[i][1]+ ' - ' + Scorers[i][0] + '</p>';
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qkjbajho/3/)

Comment: This don't answer the question, it's more a comment.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, I don't have enough rep to comment T_T.

Comment: It's only 2 more rep, you can comment from 50 rep I think.

Comment: The Scorers var is an array of players, I want to make a list of players who scored a goal, next to it I want the minute. For example if a player scored at the 5th min he will be first, a player who scored at the 22nd min will be second and on and on..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague, but you can try this:

```
var timeStart = 0;
var output = [];
function timeGenerator(timeStart) {

    var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 1);
    if (time > timeStart) {
        timeStart = time;
    } 
    output.push(timeStart); 
    output.sort();

;
    document.getElementById("Scorers").innerHTML = "</p>"+ output.toString() +"</p>";
}
```

It preserves the sorted numbers in an array which is always reprinted to the element.